# Is the result of GROUP BY should be sorted accordingly the SQL standard?

Tags: sql

Is the result of GROUP BY should be sorted accordingly the SQL standard?

Many databases return the sorted results for GROUP BY,

but is it enforced by SQL92 or other standard?

Answer (score 6):

No. `GROUP BY` has no standard impact on the order of rows returned. That's what  `ORDER BY` is designed to do.

If you're getting some kind of repeatable or predictable sort order returned by a `GROUP BY`, it's something being done in your DBMS that is not defined in the standards.

Answer (score 2):

As a previous answer has explained, no sorting is ever implied by any basic SQL construct other than `ORDER BY`.

However, to compute `GROUP BY`, either index scan or in-memory sorting may take place (to create the buckets), and such an index scan, or sorting, implies a traversal of the data in a sorted order.  So it is no accident that a particular database often behaves like this.  Do not rely on it, however, because with a different set of indexes, or even just a different query plan (which may be triggered as little as by a few inserts and/or a restart of your database server) the behavior could be quite different.

Notice also that reordering the column list in the `ORDER BY` clause will result in reliably reordering the output, whereas reordering the column list in a `GROUP BY` clause will likely have no effect whatsoever.

There is no performance cost of using a seemingly "redundant" ORDER BY.  The query plan will likely be identical, if the original one already guaranteed sorted output.

Comment: Actually, ordering is not *necessary*. I would agree it's almost always done because not doing so would vastly reduce performance, but it's not required by any SQL standard I've seen. The question asked if `GROUP BY` sort order was enforced by any standard, and the answer to that question is "No." :)

Comment: @KenWhite - Which is why I had upvoted your answer before deciding to add more detail to explain what the OP has observed and contemplated.  :-)

Comment: And why I didn't downvote yours even though it's technically not an answer to the question asked. I also wanted to clarify what you were saying, though, and thus my comment. :-)

Comment: Heck, you might not even need to restart your server, depending on your RDBMS.  And some implementations try different things depending on load, so you don't always even have to add/remove/change data, either.

Comment: OK, polished my off topic answer a bit and added a note on multi-column clauses where the difference between grouping and sorting is especially easy to observe.

Answer (score 1):

Um, sorting the output of a GROUP BY is not in the standard because there are standard algorithms for grouping that do not produce results in order.

The most common of these is the use of a hash table for doing the group by.

In addition, on a multithreaded server, the data could be sorted, but the results would be returned processor-by-processor.  There is no guarantee that the lowest order processor would be the first to return data.

And also, on a parallel machine, the data may be split among the processors using a variety of methods.  For instance, all strings that end in "a" may go to one processor.  All that end in "b" to another.  These could then be sorted locally, but the results themselves would not be sorted overall.

Databases such as mysql that guarantee a sort after the group by are making a poor design decision.  In addition to not conforming to the standard, such databases either limit the choice of algorithm or impose additional processing for ordering.

Comment: +1 for insight, but I don't believe you on mysql providing such a guarantee unless you can provide a reference.  The documentation for version 5.0 seems to indicate otherwise.